# Handle bgp protocol packet size

Tags: routes, protocols, bgp

Why BGP protocol restict its packet size less than 4096 octet？

If the BGP packet size exceeds 4096 bytes,how should I handle this？

Answer (score 3):

"Why BGP protocol restict its packet size less than 4096 octet？"

Tony Li gave the official answer in this [IDR thread](https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/idr/current/msg02405.html). To quote his answer:

> 1. First, an implementation should NOT be using a message size that
>    is different than the specified 4k message size limit.  If an
>    implementation sends messages more than 4k, then other
>    implementations will not be able to parse them.  If an implementation
>    cannot receive 4k messages, then it will also not be able to
>    interoperate.
>
> > 1a) Having a fixed size is good because it makes the protocol
> > implementations easy.  There is no point to having complexity in an
> > implementation if it provides no benefit.  Large messages don't
> > provide a wonderful benefit, as they need to be large enough to carry
> > the path attributes and associated prefixes.  For this purpose 4k is
> > probably adequate to date.
>
> > 1b) Historically, 4k was considered a bit wasteful.  Of course, it
> > was wonderfully simple compared to EGP which used fragmented
> > packets.  Care to parse a 16k jumbo-gram?  Care to debug that?  Trust
> > me, it's not fun.
>
> 2. The 4k message size is *completely independent* of the TCP window
>    size.  An implementation is perfectly free to compose any number of
>    messages, each of which is within the 4k limit.  The implementation
>    can then cram any number of messages into its TCP socket, up to the
>    buffering limits of that TCP.
>
> > 2a) Thus, the message size is *NOT* performance limiting, except when
> > an implementation could actually overfill a message.  Folks
> > maintaining current implementations might chime in here as to whether
> > or not they see this.
> > So, in summary, yes, a 4k message size limit is a fine situation *for
> >
> > BGP*, for the way that it behaves and the job that it does.  This
> > does *NOT* necessarily generalize to other protocols, (e.g. OSPF)
> > where 4k exceeds the most common MTUs.  In those cases, you'd end up
> > with fragmentation, and that's bad.

how to handle a BGP packet with a size exceeds 4096?

In the real world, we deal with this scenario by logging a BGP malformed message and then terminate the session by sending a BGP notification with code Message Header Error(1), and subcode Bad Message Length(2). Terminating the session is one of the approaches of BGP error handling. You may refer to BGP error handling [rfc7606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7606).

Answer (score 0):

Just how the spec was written.  Check out http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1771.html for more details.  This means you shouldn't, in theory, ever receive a BGP packet greater than 4k.  Perhaps they were thinking that large packets sent containing large routing table updates and the likes shouldn't interfere with large data transfers so they break up the packets to utilize different queues. That's a total SWAG though.  :)